# Creating an Array with Subscripts and Superscripts

Tags: replacement, symbolic, list-manipulation, subscript, automation

I would like to figure out how to construct an array using subscripts and superscripts based on the following info:

```
Cs = {1, 3, 5};
Ss = {1, -1, 1};
Rules = {1 -> "+", -1 -> "-"};
Ss1 = Ss /. Rules;
```

If I try, for example:

```
{SubsuperscriptBox["c", Cs[[1]], Ss1[[1]]], 
  SubsuperscriptBox["c", Cs[[2]], Ss1[[2]]], 
  SubsuperscriptBox["c", Cs[[3]], Ss1[[3]]]} // DisplayForm
```

I get an output of:

$\{c^{+}_1,c^{-}_3,c^{+}_5\}$

This is what I want to get. However, I want to do this more automatically, rather than hard-coding it like I just did. I mean, I should be able to vary the arrays Cs and Ss to something arbitrary. For example, say I have instead:

```
 Cs = {1, 2, 4, 5};
 Ss = {1, -1, 1, -1};
 Rules = {1 -> "+", -1 -> "-"};
 Ss1 = Ss /. Rules;
```

I should then get:

$\{c^{+}_1,c^{-}_2,c^{+}_4,c^{-}_5\}$

Of course, I could just change the second block of code, but I want to see if there is a more clean way of doing this, without me needing to manually change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use, e.g.,

```
MapThread[
 SubsuperscriptBox["c", ##] &,
 {Cs, Ss1}
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Cs = {1, 2, 4, 5};
Ss = {1, -1, 1, -1};
Ss1 = Ss /. {1 -> "+", -1 -> "-"};

Thread[Subsuperscript["c", Cs, Ss1]]
```

[image]

You can also [`Apply (@@@)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) the function  `Subsuperscript["c", ##]&` to pairs of values from `Cs` and `Ss1` (that is, to `Transpose[{Cs, Ss1}}]`):

```
Subsuperscript["c", ##] & @@@ Transpose[{Cs, Ss1}]
```

[image]